# How to serialize xml array AND class properties using C# XML serialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I have a class that is inherited from `List<T>` and also has some properties, like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class DropList : List<DropItem>
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int FinalDropCount{get; set;}
}
```

This class is serialized to xml as part of a larger class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Location
{
    public DropList DropList{get; set;}
    ....
}
```

The problem is, serializer sees my list as a collection; the resulting XML contians only list elements, but not class properties (FinalDropCount in this case). This is an example of outputted XML:

```
<Location xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <DropList>
        <DropItem ProtoId="3" Count="0" Minimum="0" Maximum="0" />
        <DropItem ProtoId="4" Count="0" Minimum="0" Maximum="0" />
    </DropList>
    ....
</Location>
```

Is there some way to save *both* list contents and properties without resorting to implementing `IXmlSerializable` by hand?

Comment: Why do you want to serialize the properties?  Usually what interests you is the data contained in the class, aka the current values all the variables have.  Properties are just a way to access those values.  Can you clarify?

Comment: These properties are part of the data. Think of it this way: DropList is a list of DropItems with some attached data, like FinalDropCount. So, I need to save and load all of the data - both list and properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have other alternatives that you can consider.

Alternative one - Move to composition instead of inheritance:

```
public class DropInfo
{
    [XmlArray("Drops")]
    [XmlArrayItem("DropItem")]
    public List<DropItem> Items { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int FinalDropCount { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public DropInfo DropInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Alternative two - Move the properties outside the collection:

```
public class DropList : List<DropItem>
{
}

public class Location
{
    public DropList DropList { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int FinalDropCount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's what I am doing now. But semantically it is better to have a DropList that _is_ a List - if that is at all possible.